# I want to reply to a mod commenting on a locked post. How?

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies, deleted-posts

My post was deleted and I want to reply to the mod commenting on it after deletion. How can I do this?

[image: The comment]

Comment: You realize that post was _two weeks_ before the winter bash even starts, yes? Chances are someone else would have just created a new post and not realized yours was there once the first secret hat was found. It really didn't need to exist yet.

Comment: @Kendra that explains why i saw a Winter Bash Secret Hats Question with an answer appear an hour ago and was deleted when Winter Bash hasn't even started yet and as such no Secret Hats even exist

Answer (score 19):

> I want to reply to the mod commenting on it after deletion. How can I do this?

### You don't.

Mods can comment on deleted posts so that they can explain why the post was deleted or otherwise assist the author in better using the site.

If a moderator comments on a post either after deletion or immediately before, consider it a courtesy and pay attention to the explanation given. **Do not** mistake it for an invitation to discuss the matter; if there was room for discussion, the post would not have been deleted. If you have further questions, you can post them here.

You may, of course, always dispute the actions of any moderator by creating a post on meta. However, you should generally do so only when you believe a mistake has been made; in particular, don't waste time disputing the deletion of posts you shouldn't have created in the first place.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: It still doesn't.

Comment: @haykam Your question was "How do I respond to a mod about this?" Shog's answer is "You don't." That's an answer, and an appropriate one. Consider "How do I drive from New York, USA to London, England?" Since there's currently no way to do that... "You don't."

Comment: @Shog9 Still doesn't answer my question. I wanted to ask the mod a followup question. Specifically, I was wondering when it would be acceptable to be asked.

Comment: And I'm saying, **DO NOT DO THAT.** If you have a question, you can ask it here on meta, directed at anyone who has the information necessary to answer.

Comment: That'd be a waste of space.

Comment: Then you have an easy afternoon ahead of you!

Comment: I dunno know about you, but my mom taught me at an early age that sometimes you need to take "no" as an answer.

Comment: @Shog9 why isn't flagging an option? Isn't it better than posting it here in the open?

Comment: You generally want to avoid trying to carry on a conversation via flags, @Shadow. Also, you can't target a specific moderator with a flag any more than you can with a question.

Comment: @Shog9 I mean to appeal the deletion of the post in general.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's fine @ShadowWizard.